# Stateful C++ global void function pointer

Tags: c++

Is it possible to create a function with a single parameter, which returns a pointer to a globally scoped void returning, parameterless function?

I ask in the sense of embedded hardware, where I'm trying to define a series of interrupt service routines to attach to digital pins.

An example of what I mean:

```
#define MAX_BUTTONS 5

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUTTONS; i++) {
        attachInterrupt(i, isrForI(i), RISING);
    }
}

typedef void (*Isr)(void);

Isr isrForI(int i)
{
    // Return a function of type Isr which calls handleInterrupt(i)
}

void handleInterrupt(int i)
{
    // Do something with i
}
```

The issue here is not knowing how to be generic enough in `isrForI`, as I need it to be extensible such that `MAX_BUTTONS` can be any number.

Comment: Can you extend your example to show the function that `isrFor(i)` returns.

Comment: You want state, but with a bare function pointer? Not a functor?

Comment: Directions unclear. Do you want to generate these void functions on the fly or select them from an existing pool based on the integer parameter? If the latter, it looks like you are rlooking for an array of function pointers. Or perhaps you mean the same function but with different states attached to it?

Comment: All valid comments, will edit and add more information

Comment: The problem witht he question (as written) is that the answer is simply "Yes", which you could have figured out by trying.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a simple yes-no question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know `MAX_BUTTONS` at compile time, you could probably use templates to avoid having to create runtime function:

```
#define MAX_BUTTONS 5

typedef void (*Isr)(void);

template <int N>
void handleInterrupt() { /* int i = N; */ }


template <int N>
Isr isrForI() {
    return handleInterrupt<N>;
}

template <int N>
struct attach_interrupts {
    static void attach() {
        attachInterrupt(N, isrForI<N>(), RISING); 
        attach_interrupts<N - 1>::attach();
    }
};

template <>
struct attach_interrupts<0> {
    static void attach() {
        attachInterrupt(0, isrForI<0>(), RISING); 
    }
};

int main() {
    attach_interrupts<MAX_BUTTONS - 1>::attach();
}
```

The only difference with your code is that it attaches interrupts from `MAX_BUTTONS - 1` to `0` instead of `0` to `MAX_BUTTONS - 1` (but you can easily adapt the templates).

As mentioned by @StoryTeller in the comments, if you want to keep `handleInterrupt(int)`, you could simply do:

```
void handleInterrupt(int i) { /* Your original handleInterrupt... */ }

template <int N>
void handleInterrupt() { 
    // Call the original one:
    handleInterrupt(N);
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `handleInterrupt` doesn't have to be a template. It can be a regular function and the OP can pass `N` to it as a parameter, as they originally wanted.

Comment: @StoryTeller How would you pass the `N` since `isForI` returns a pointer to the n-th `handleInterrupt` function?

Comment: I was thrown of by the name, but if the OP already has `handleInterrupt(int)` that they want to keep, the template body should be `void handleInterrupt() { handleInterrupt(N); }`

Comment: @StoryTeller I have edited the answer to mention that possibility, thanks.